# Changing speed in loop animation

Tags: animation

I recently modelled a propeller and made it spin with a loop animation.

My goal is to make the thrust(spinning speed) of the propeller increase when the chopter takes off, just like in real life.

In other words: I want the loop animation to have different speed throughout the whole animation

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you describe how you get the loop animation? *Extrapolation mode* --> *Cyclic F-Modifier* or something else?